# Lightning component removing multiple values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a customer community component built with data fething from a child custom object with data from parent object as well. I want to display only none value from parent object for multiple rows from child object. I want to hide value 'A' from 2nd and 3rd rows

```
Column 1 Column 2
A              X
A              Y
A              Z
```

**COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component controller="MyActiveModuleAuraController" access="global" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
  <aura:attribute name="moduleRows" type="Assessment_Module__c[]" /> 

      <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS102/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" 
                  scripts="/resource/Jquery" />


    <div class="slds">  
        <p>
            <b> My Active Training Modules</b>
        </p>
        <br>
        </br>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked">
          <thead>
               <tr class ="slds-text-heading--label"> 
                    <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-4">Module Name</td>
                    <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-4">Resourse Issued</td>
                    <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-4">Assessor</td>
                    <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-4">Standard Name</td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.moduleRows}">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Module Name"> {!cell.Module__c} </td>
                        <td data-label="Resource Issued">
                            <ui:outputDate value="{!cell.Resource_Issued__c}" /> </td>
                        <td data-label="Assessor"> {!cell.Assessor__c} </td>
                        <td data-label="Standard Name"> {!cell.Standard_Name__c} </td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
         helper.myModules(component);

    }
})
```

**HELPER**

```
({
   myModules: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getMyActiveModules");
      action.setCallback(this, function(a){
          component.set("v.moduleRows", a.getReturnValue());
      });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }   
})
```

**APEX CONTROLLER**

```
public class MyActiveModuleAuraController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Assessment_Module__c> getMyActiveModules(){
        //Get logged in user details
        User loggedInUser = [SELECT Id, ContactId
                             FROM User
                             WHERE ID=: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('=loggedInUser===='+loggedInUser);

        return [select Assessor__c, Resource_Issued__c, Module__c, Standard_Name__c, Module_Completed_date__c 
                FROM Assessment_Module__c WHERE  Completed__c = False AND TP_Status__c    ='Active'
              //  AND First_Name__c ='Trainee'
              AND Trainee__c =:loggedInUser.ContactId];
}
}
```

Comment: you can use aura:if to do a conditional rendering , however please post your code example so that we can take a look

Comment: Thank you for the sample. Kindly take a look into this small snippet for conditional rendering. You can use aura:if or aura:renderIf to conditionally display values. Here since you have mentioned that you wanted to hide the value A from 2nd and 3rd Rows , use an expression like "{!v.myvalue != null}" or something that suits your requirement. Dpaste snippet : http://dpaste.com/1ZCDXS2 and conditional expressions : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm

Comment: That being said, the recommended documentation also states that we must avoid using aura:if wherever we can .. as it can hinder with our performance. Hence you can use a CSS class to hide or display your values. For example use a class called ltngShow and ltngHide set the properties to display. And you can determine the dynamic css class in your JS controllers or helpers. However in our case, As we do not have a lot a mark-up, hence using aura:if or aura:renderIf should be fine https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_conditional_markup.htm

Comment: Thanks Sumuga for the solution. I tried but no values visible at all on that column.  Anything missing??